# How can you load next the level after you destroy the last clone c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, counter, destroy

I am almost complete with my game but I am just stuck on one part. I have to implement some statement that says when the last clone is destroyed the next level is loaded. Except I do not know how to do that. I have a respawner which makes like 20 clones of a sphere and when I collide with them they disappear. After 20 clones have been destroyed I want to advance to the next level. Can anyone help me out?

Here's my respawner:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject objectToSpawn;
    public int numberOfEnemies;
    private float spawnRadius = 5;
    private Vector3 spawnPosition;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start ()
    {
        SpawnObject();  
    }

    void Update () {}

    void SpawnObject() 
    {
        for (int i= 0; i < numberOfEnemies; i++)  
        { 
            spawnPosition = transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * spawnRadius; 
            Instantiate(objectToSpawn, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my BoxDestroy:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BoxDestroy : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    } 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Each time you destroy an enemy keep track of the current destroyed count using a static variable. That's the first step!

Comment: lol you made that sound easy.. however i am a certified noob using Unity and programming also. Is there any videos i can watch or something to learn how to do that ?

Comment: The first part I'm sure you're capable of. You've done things harder than that. Declare an int variable and increment it in your if statement, right after calling Destroy. As for changing levels, that's a different story. Search it up on the Unity website.

Comment: I cannot provide any code right now as I'm on my phone, but I'm sure with determination you'll get there.

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class BoxDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

 int numberOfEnemies = 0


 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
 {
  if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
  { Destroy(gameObject);
   numberOfEnemies = i++;

  if(numberOfEnemies == 10){
   Application.Loadlevel(0);
  
  }

  }
 }

  
}

Comment: Theres some code i tried still nothing..

Comment: You need to watch tutorials.there is a spaceshooter tutorial on unity's official page.i watched it when i started to learn unity3d.it teached me a lot.you cant go further just trying.you get bored if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a tag for spheres like `Enemy` or what ever you want.
2. In `BoxDestroy` class, Before you destroy the object, calculate the count of remaining objects and if its equal to one then load another scene:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class BoxDestroy : MonoBehaviour 
   {   
       void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
       {
           if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
           {

               GameObject[] remainingObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
               if (remainingObj.Length == 1)
               {
                   Application.LoadLevel("name of level you want to load");
               }

               Destroy(gameObject);
           }
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: @Wes Your welcome, Please mark it as answer if it helps. tnx